# Is there an editor out there that allows me to test PL/SQL scripts without a connection?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I work at a facility that does not allow me access to a Oracle Database offsite. So I can't connect to the server through a Oracle client connection right now, because of COVID I'm forced to work from home.

I'm required right now to write a PL/SQL script that will update records across the entire database, however I don't know anything about setting up a test environment on my home computer so that I can run the script in a controlled environment to test it before I bring it back on site.

At one of my previous jobs, they had a PROD, PREPROD, and so forth copies of Oracle databases that one could run the script on before I sent it up the chain to production. The setup we're using doesn't have that, just the production database and thus we have the problem with our workflow that we have one shot to get it right.

So my question is, is there an editor out there for Oracle that will allow me to create a test database, so that I can run the script on that, see the results, edit it to make it work right, before I bring it back to work and run it on our production server? I'm opposed to installing a full Oracle database implementation on my own computer for licensing reasons and/or honestly I don't know what I'm doing setting up an Oracle server on my own (Tried it, couldn't even find documentation on it).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Express Edition (XE) is free so - no licensing reasons here.

If you want, you can download pre-configured Virtual Box machine which has the database already installed, along with SQL Developer GUI tool to access it so you're *up and running* in a matter of minutes.

Alternatively, create an account on https://apex.oracle.com/en/; it is also free, gives you certain quota (was 25MB, don't know how much is it now, possibly somewhat more than that) which is enough to try your queries.

Or, use https://dbfiddle.uk/

As you can see, there are various options; pick the one that suits you best.

Comment: Where would I download the preconfigured Virtual Box setup?

Comment: Right here: https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html

Comment: Two related tips for other readers: the Vagrant files are easy ways to install DBs in VirtualBox: https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects  And there is always "Oracle Cloud Free Tier" that could be used (for free) : https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/  Some services are always free, others have a trial period.  There are various resources, blogs etc that walk through creating and connecting, e.g. https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases